# Converting String to a Class , Crystal Report Printing

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to make my code a little perfect , i m using Crystal Report , for a project , i use the code which can print a Crystal Report faster without choosing a printer, the problem is , i use a lot of crystal report , and i want to create a function that can help me , normally i use that method :

```
Select Case string_printer

        Case "cristale1"
            cristale1.PrintOptions.PaperSource = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource.Auto
            cristale1.PrintToPrinter(NB_Copy.Value, True, 0, 2)
            cristale1.Close()

        Case "cristale2"
            cristale2.PrintOptions.PaperSource = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource.Auto
            cristale2.PrintToPrinter(NB_Copy.Value, True, 0, 2)
            cristale2.Close()

        Case "cristale3"
            cristale3.PrintOptions.PaperSource = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource.Auto
            cristale3.PrintToPrinter(NB_Copy.Value, True, 0, 2)
            cristale3.Close()

End Select
```

what i try to do is some thing like that :

```
Sub Print_Report(string_printer as String , NB_Copy as Integer)
    Dim class_here =  // CHANGING THE STRING to the Class using the string_printer
    Dim data = Ctype(class_here,ReportClass)
    data .PrintOptions.PaperSource = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource.Auto
    data .PrintToPrinter(NB_Copy, True, 0, 2)
    data .Close()
End Sub
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: The problem is that you "use a lot of crystal report"? What's the actual question here?

Comment: normally , people use one crystal report , but in my case , i use 20 crystal report in a single form with one crystal report viewer, so , i try to create a function to reduce lot of line in my base code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(My VB is a little rusty) How about

```
Dim printer;

Select Case string_printer
    Case "cristale1"
        printer = cristale1;
    Case "cristale2"
        printer = cristale2;
    Case "cristale3"
        printer = cristale3;
End Select

printer.PrintOptions.PaperSource = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource.Auto
printer.PrintToPrinter(NB_Copy.Value, True, 0, 2)
printer.Close()
```

ETA: Found this

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(string className)
```

so this should work

```
Sub Print_Report(string_printer as String , NB_Copy as Integer)
  Dim class_here = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(string_printer)
  Dim data = Ctype(class_here,ReportClass)
  data .PrintOptions.PaperSource = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource.Auto
  data .PrintToPrinter(NB_Copy, True, 0, 2)
data .Close()
End Sub
```

or you could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx)

```
Activator.CreateInstance("PersonInfo", "Person");
```

Comment: thanks , i already do it yesterday , but still have more and more line for each crystal report I have

Comment: @user3737184 added some more that might work for you.

Comment: i will try it now , give you the feedback in 1min

Comment: it give me the following msg : the reference object is not set to an instance of an object

Comment: the ligne : Dim class_here = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(string_printer)
return Nothing

Comment: Did that fix it?  as I said I'm not that great at VB

Comment: no , but i try the reference that you give me : 
Activator.CreateInstance("PersonInfo", "Person")

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like (sorry, that's C#):

```
public Printer GetByName(string name) {
    return this.GetType().GetFields().First(f => f.Name == name).GetValue(this) as Printer;
}
```

[GetFields docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx). This uses reflection, so if you access this code very often, it might be inefficient. However, I don't think that will be a problem. If it will, though, I'd recommend to stick with your current approach.

Note, that use of reflection creates non-obvious usages of `cristale1,2,3` fields. This should probably be documented somewhere so that your code readers know for sure that those are necessary and `GetByName` is where they're used.

A working example which shows the basics can be found [here](http://ideone.com/iL9WtS).

Comment: don't worry i will translate it to VB and i give you my feedback , Thanks

Comment: @user3737184 okay. Let us know if that worked for you

Comment: not yet , i m sorry  , do you have an example to try it ?

Comment: if i mind , i must create all the instance of the Crystal Report that i have and that so i can call the method , am i correct ?

Comment: From what I know of your code, the `cristale1,2,3` are fields of your class. Once you put the function as described above to your class you should be able to access those fields using their names.

Comment: yes that's true , but , i don't know in future , may be , i will add more Crystal report , so i must declare those crystal and that so to others

Comment: Could you please re-formulate your statement? I can't understand what your concern is

Comment: I 'm sorry, I was mean , I can not create variables all the time for crystal report that I create, but if there is a possibility to get the name of crystal report used in crystal report viewer it will repair all

Comment: What variables are you talking about? Where are you creating them? My particular answer has nothing to do with crystal reports, so if you could speak in more general terms (like field, instance, class) that would be highly appreciated.